# edit to answer looks like spam

Tags: support

I see an edit on my answer.
The anonymous user has added many urls to my answer and deleted most of my post.
Should I reject this edit?
[Question in gis stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5011/how-to-join-2-shape-files-and-create-a-new-shape-file-using-arcobjects/5013#5013)

Comment: The record shows that two users rejected this attempted edit about an hour after you posted this question: the community is doing its job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it feels like vandalism then reject it. I cannot see any suggested edits though - so you probably already did reject it.

Comment: hmm strange. I didn't know how an anonimous user could have edited  first. Now there is no sign of an edit! I did "skip" it but thought that would just leave it for investigation.